# how to use elseif statement in dom php html find

Tags: php, html

How to add statement, when I search and it doesnt exist on the url, it will show nothing.html?

```
$url1 = "http://www.pengadaan.net/tend_src_cont2.php?src_nm=";    
$url2 = $_GET['src_nm']."&src_prop=";    
$url3 = $_GET['src_prop'];    
$url = $url1.$url2.$url3;    
$html = file_get_html($url);    
if (method_exists($html,"find")) {    
    echo "<ul>";    
    foreach($html->find('div[class=pengadaan-item] h1[] a[]') as $element ) {    
        echo ("<li>".$element."</li>");
    }
    echo "</ul>";    
    echo $url;      
}
else {
}
```

Comment: That's how: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: can you help me wrtie the condition ? @zerkms

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do you want to know how to add an `elseif` statement? And have it do what exactly?

Comment: no. i mean, i wanna know the condition if, if find(..) == null, it will show nothing.html. can you help me @SpencerWieczorek ?

Comment: Do you want to echo the text `nothing.html` or move to the page `nothing.html`?

Comment: yes @SpencerWieczorek, move to the page `nothing.html`

Comment: So you want to find if there's nothing and if there's nothing then you want to load nothing but if there isn't nothing then there is nothing to load. Is that correct....

Comment: im so confused. i want to find in the url, if there is something match keywords, it will showed up , if not , it will go to `nothing.html` @Billy

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to move to another page in PHP. you can do `header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/nothing.php");` or you can have PHP `echo` JavaScript to do a reidrect (if you already defined your headers):

```
if (method_exists($html,"find")) { // If 'find exist'
    ...
} else { // Otherwise it does not exist
    header("Location: http://www.pengadaan.net/nothing.php"); // redirect here
}
```

Or if you already sent you headers you can get around it using JavaScript:

```
    ...
} else {
    echo '<script>window.location.replace("http://www.pengadaan.net/nothing.php")</script>';
}
```

Comment: Sir, can i send you an email of my file. i want you to check it. than you will know what mean. ??

Comment: @AlfianChandra Is what I said above not what you wanted? I don't think sending your file to me is necessary (your snippet of code is fine). Is the `method_exists` doing the keyword matching? Or have you not done it?

Comment: Sorry sir, Im a little confused here, bad english.im grabbing.and show it from local host. sir ?

Comment: @AlfianChandra Alright, so just use the URI `/nothing.php` if your website is not "www.pengadaan.net".

Comment: @AlfianChandra I miss-placed a semi-colon on the second example. What error are you getting?

Comment: i write like this. and it doesnt goto nothing.php sir.

`if (method_exists($html,"find")) {
echo "<ul>";
foreach($html->find('div[class=pengadaan-item] h1[] a[]') as $element ){
echo ("<li>".$element."</li>");
}echo "</ul>";
}else{
 header("Location: http://localhost/nothing.php");
}`